# most efficient way to bulk fetch by known IDS

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

What is the 'best' way to fetch a bunch of documents assuming that I have a list of IDs

I know I could try various things but at small scale probably all options have similar performance. So far I have tried nothing - just read docs

Maybe there is no 'best' way but what would be the trade-offs between various methods (speed, cost, overall throughput,...)

Sigh - I knew this would get down voted - along the lines of 'what have you tried', 'we wont write your code for you' etc. I cannot do meaningful perf analysis till I have thousands of parallel requests coming simultaneously on terabytes of data. I swear I am not lazy or unwilling to put work in , just dont want to get into production and find I have perf issues and then be told 'why on earth did you do it that way?'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some general tips on the best way to perform reads with DocumentDB.

- If you have a small number of documents, then using `ReadDocumentAsync` will be the best way to do this, across multiple threads each fetching a document using `partition key` and `id`. Each read is 1 RU per 1KB document, and under 10 ms at p99.
- If you have a large batch of documents, then using a query like `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.partitionKey = 'pk' AND c.id IN ('1','2',..., 'N')` will be more efficient, i.e. fewer connections from the client, and also fewer RUs on the server side (typically < 1 RU per document returned).
- If you need to fetch data across multiple partition keys, then it's harder to tell if individual reads or a single query would perform better. This requires a more detailed testing and depends on the number of documents read and number of distinct partition keys.

Comment: i am thinking of maybe 1000 IDs. Doing 1000 round trips seems wrong. Thats what I already do on Azure Table storage and it kills me

Comment: You can just use the SQL IN query approach with the 1000 IDs.

Comment: There is a 4th option. It's similar to Aravind's second option except it'll work across multiple partitions. First query for the partitioning ranges with `https://{your endpoint domain}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{your collection's uri fragment}/pkranges`. Then split your arrays of IDs by pkrange and query those partitions in parallel. Note, this could fail if DocumentDB decides to change the partitioning after you retrieve it but I think that's rare enough as long as you aren't changing your requested throughput.

Comment: Note - there is a limit on 32k for a sql statment. THis puts an upper limit on the number of guids that can be included

Comment: When you have WAY more IDs than 1000, what would be the approach?  I'm batching the ids up, but then my request rate is too high.

Comment: @AravindKrishnaR., As you mentioned in the second approach worked but if I want o check the exact match for items what should I do? (Checking name in the list of string)